Recovering MDADM Expansion failure due to power outage
I had a raid 6 array consisting of 6 5TB drives, and I was adding 4 more when the power went out.
When I run:
mdadm --assemble --verbose --force /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdi1 /dev/sdj1 /dev/sdk1 /dev/sdl1 /dev/sdm1 /dev/sdn1 /dev/sdo1

I get:
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md1
mdadm: /dev/sda1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 9.
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdi1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 5.
mdadm: /dev/sdj1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdk1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/sdl1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 4.
mdadm: /dev/sdm1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 8.
mdadm: /dev/sdn1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 7.
mdadm: /dev/sdo1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 6.
mdadm: added /dev/sdc1 to /dev/md1 as 0 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdj1 to /dev/md1 as 2 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdk1 to /dev/md1 as 3 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdl1 to /dev/md1 as 4 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdi1 to /dev/md1 as 5 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdo1 to /dev/md1 as 6
mdadm: added /dev/sdn1 to /dev/md1 as 7 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdm1 to /dev/md1 as 8 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sda1 to /dev/md1 as 9 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md1 as 1
mdadm: /dev/md1 assembled from 2 drives - not enough to start the array.

Examining all the disks I get:
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : aedf8d12:48037c00:6fbe8b20:f5346024
           Name : r720:1  (local to host r720)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 30 14:58:58 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 10

 Avail Dev Size : 9766176701 (4656.88 GiB 5000.28 GB)
     Array Size : 39064686592 (37254.99 GiB 40002.24 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9766171648 (4656.87 GiB 5000.28 GB)
    Data Offset : 260096 sectors
     New Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5279f688:03cf2a10:d6e1cbfa:7b32285e

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 18159947776 (17318.68 GiB 18595.79 GB)
  Delta Devices : 4 (6->10)

    Update Time : Wed Oct  9 17:30:51 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : efc1a707 - correct
         Events : 4904849

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 9
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : aedf8d12:48037c00:6fbe8b20:f5346024
           Name : r720:1  (local to host r720)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 30 14:58:58 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 10

 Avail Dev Size : 9766176768 (4656.88 GiB 5000.28 GB)
     Array Size : 39064686592 (37254.99 GiB 40002.24 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9766171648 (4656.87 GiB 5000.28 GB)
    Data Offset : 260096 sectors
     New Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : fd80bd65:3e43e35b:fd3ec1c5:a371dca7

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 18161201152 (17319.87 GiB 18597.07 GB)
  Delta Devices : 4 (6->10)

    Update Time : Wed Oct  9 17:31:16 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : 2d10ff98 - correct
         Events : 4904851

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : aedf8d12:48037c00:6fbe8b20:f5346024
           Name : r720:1  (local to host r720)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 30 14:58:58 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 10

 Avail Dev Size : 9766176701 (4656.88 GiB 5000.28 GB)
     Array Size : 39064686592 (37254.99 GiB 40002.24 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9766171648 (4656.87 GiB 5000.28 GB)
    Data Offset : 260096 sectors
     New Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5cb0f838:e2e130f8:044a0e8e:c1b457f4

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 18155274240 (17314.22 GiB 18591.00 GB)
  Delta Devices : 4 (6->10)

    Update Time : Wed Oct  9 17:30:02 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : b0ad3b29 - correct
         Events : 4904845

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdi1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : aedf8d12:48037c00:6fbe8b20:f5346024
           Name : r720:1  (local to host r720)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 30 14:58:58 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 10

 Avail Dev Size : 9766176701 (4656.88 GiB 5000.28 GB)
     Array Size : 39064686592 (37254.99 GiB 40002.24 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9766171648 (4656.87 GiB 5000.28 GB)
    Data Offset : 260096 sectors
     New Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 7a80cd4b:0574311b:9d5102c9:e2111544

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 18155274240 (17314.22 GiB 18591.00 GB)
  Delta Devices : 4 (6->10)

    Update Time : Wed Oct  9 17:30:02 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : 71340229 - correct
         Events : 4904845

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdj1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : aedf8d12:48037c00:6fbe8b20:f5346024
           Name : r720:1  (local to host r720)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 30 14:58:58 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 10

 Avail Dev Size : 9766176701 (4656.88 GiB 5000.28 GB)
     Array Size : 39064686592 (37254.99 GiB 40002.24 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9766171648 (4656.87 GiB 5000.28 GB)
    Data Offset : 260096 sectors
     New Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f80ad65d:c25d3b0d:38f36b41:05a31d02

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 18155274240 (17314.22 GiB 18591.00 GB)
  Delta Devices : 4 (6->10)

    Update Time : Wed Oct  9 17:30:02 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : abb8a91d - correct
         Events : 4904845

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdk1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : aedf8d12:48037c00:6fbe8b20:f5346024
           Name : r720:1  (local to host r720)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 30 14:58:58 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 10

 Avail Dev Size : 9766176701 (4656.88 GiB 5000.28 GB)
     Array Size : 39064686592 (37254.99 GiB 40002.24 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9766171648 (4656.87 GiB 5000.28 GB)
    Data Offset : 260096 sectors
     New Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b59335ce:9766c75a:011b1cb6:a7d5b6ad

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 18155274240 (17314.22 GiB 18591.00 GB)
  Delta Devices : 4 (6->10)

    Update Time : Wed Oct  9 17:30:02 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : 89ed951d - correct
         Events : 4904845

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdl1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : aedf8d12:48037c00:6fbe8b20:f5346024
           Name : r720:1  (local to host r720)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 30 14:58:58 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 10

 Avail Dev Size : 9766176701 (4656.88 GiB 5000.28 GB)
     Array Size : 39064686592 (37254.99 GiB 40002.24 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9766171648 (4656.87 GiB 5000.28 GB)
    Data Offset : 260096 sectors
     New Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5a85aa3e:d22f71b8:1e98ba15:c3ffcd59

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 18155274240 (17314.22 GiB 18591.00 GB)
  Delta Devices : 4 (6->10)

    Update Time : Wed Oct  9 17:30:02 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : 63c1f737 - correct
         Events : 4904845

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdm1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : aedf8d12:48037c00:6fbe8b20:f5346024
           Name : r720:1  (local to host r720)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 30 14:58:58 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 10

 Avail Dev Size : 9766176701 (4656.88 GiB 5000.28 GB)
     Array Size : 39064686592 (37254.99 GiB 40002.24 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9766171648 (4656.87 GiB 5000.28 GB)
    Data Offset : 260096 sectors
     New Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 998a0fd9:dd59ecfb:dc5cdb50:e4d29810

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 18159947776 (17318.68 GiB 18595.79 GB)
  Delta Devices : 4 (6->10)

    Update Time : Wed Oct  9 17:30:51 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : 341c5e99 - correct
         Events : 4904849

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 8
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdn1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : aedf8d12:48037c00:6fbe8b20:f5346024
           Name : r720:1  (local to host r720)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 30 14:58:58 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 10

 Avail Dev Size : 9766176701 (4656.88 GiB 5000.28 GB)
     Array Size : 39064686592 (37254.99 GiB 40002.24 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9766171648 (4656.87 GiB 5000.28 GB)
    Data Offset : 260096 sectors
     New Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 0875abf4:f3a14083:f8628db6:f37f9fda

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 18159947776 (17318.68 GiB 18595.79 GB)
  Delta Devices : 4 (6->10)

    Update Time : Wed Oct  9 17:30:51 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : 6c5444b - correct
         Events : 4904849

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 7
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdo1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : aedf8d12:48037c00:6fbe8b20:f5346024
           Name : r720:1  (local to host r720)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan 30 14:58:58 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 10

 Avail Dev Size : 9766176701 (4656.88 GiB 5000.28 GB)
     Array Size : 39064686592 (37254.99 GiB 40002.24 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9766171648 (4656.87 GiB 5000.28 GB)
    Data Offset : 260096 sectors
     New Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 16495032:521c31e6:e1e498c9:41302f11

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 18161201152 (17319.87 GiB 18597.07 GB)
  Delta Devices : 4 (6->10)

    Update Time : Wed Oct  9 17:31:04 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 32 sectors
       Checksum : f11c04fc - correct
         Events : 4904850

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 6
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

Am I a ship out of luck, and dead in the water, or is this something that I can somehow rebuild?
Is there some way of just ignoring the "possibly out of date" and assembling anyway?
